# Abstraction for monadic recursion with "unless"

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm trying to work out if it's possible to write an abstraction for the following situation. Suppose I have a type `a` with function `a -> m Bool` e.g. `MVar Bool` and `readMVar`. To abstract this concept out I create a newtype wrapper for the type and its function:

```
newtype MPredicate m a = MPredicate (a,a -> m Bool)
```

I can define a fairly simple operation like so:

```
doUnless :: (Monad m) => Predicate m a -> m () -> m ()
doUnless (MPredicate (a,mg)) g = mg a >>= \b -> unless b g

main = do
   b <- newMVar False
   let mpred = MPredicate (b,readMVar)
   doUnless mpred (print "foo")
```

In this case `doUnless` would print "foo". *Aside: I'm not sure whether a type class might be more appropriate to use instead of a newtype.*

Now take the code below, which outputs an incrementing number then waits a second and repeats. It does this until it receives a "turn off" instruction via the MVar.

```
foobar :: MVar Bool -> IO ()
foobar mvb = foobar' 0
    where
        foobar' :: Int -> IO ()
        foobar' x = readMVar mvb >>= \b -> unless b $ do
            let x' = x + 1
            print x'
            threadDelay 1000000
            foobar' x'

goTillEnter :: MVar Bool -> IO ()
goTillEnter mv = do
    _ <- getLine
    _ <- takeMVar mv
    putMVar mv True

main = do
   mvb <- newMVar False
   forkIO $ foobar mvb
   goTillEnter mvb
```

Is it possible to refactor `foobar` so that it uses `MPredicate` and `doUnless`?

Ignoring the actual implementation of `foobar'` I can think of a simplistic way of doing something similar:

```
cycleUnless :: x -> (x -> x) -> MPredicate m a -> m ()
cycleUnless x g mp = let g' x' = doUnless mp (g' $ g x')
                     in  g' $ g x
```

*Aside: I feel like `fix` could be used to make the above neater, though I still have trouble working out how to use it*

But `cycleUnless` won't work on `foobar` because the type of `foobar'` is actually `Int -> IO ()` (from the use of `print x'`).

I'd also like to take this abstraction further, so that it can work threading around a Monad. With stateful Monads it becomes even harder. E.g.

```
-- EDIT: Updated the below to show an example of how the code is used
{- ^^ some parent function which has the MVar ^^ -}
cycleST :: (forall s. ST s (STArray s Int Int)) -> IO ()
cycleST sta = readMVar mvb >>= \b -> unless b $ do
    n <- readMVar someMVar
    i <- readMVar someOtherMVar
    let sta' = do
            arr <- sta
            x <- readArray arr n
            writeArray arr n (x + i)
            return arr
        y = runSTArray sta'
    print y
    cycleST sta'
```

I have something similar to the above working with RankNTypes. Now there's the additional problem of trying to thread through the existential `s`, which is not likely to type check if threaded around through an abstraction the likes of `cycleUnless`.

Additionally, this is simplified to make the question easier to answer. I also use a set of semaphores built from `MVar [MVar ()]` similar to the skip channel example in [the MVar module](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Control-Concurrent-MVar.html). If I can solve the above problem I plan to generalize the semaphores as well.

Ultimately this isn't some blocking problem. I have 3 components of the application operating in a cycle off the same `MVar Bool` but doing fairly different asynchronous tasks. In each one I have written a custom function that performs the appropriate cycle.

I'm trying to learn the "don't write large programs" approach. What I'd like to do is refactor chunks of code into their own mini libraries so that I'm not building a large program but assembling lots of small ones. But so far this particular abstraction is escaping me.

Any thoughts on how I might go about this are very much appreciated!

Comment: `readArray sta 1` doesn't check in `cycleST`. I also don't quite get what you're trying to do with `cycleST`.

Comment: It should type check with `(forall s. ST s (STArray s Int Int)) -> IO ()`. I use something like `cycleST` to inject IO data into the `STArray`. I'll edit the question to clarify.

Comment: I mean, `readArray :: STArray s i e -> i -> ST s e` (when specialized to ST), while `sta :: ST s (STArray s Int Int)`, so `readArray sta x` can't be well-typed. My GHC duly rejects it, as well.

Comment: You are correct! Need to bind the STArray using `<-`. My bad. Updated again.

Comment: Well that took me way more edits to get right than I'd care to admit! But it should be fine now.

Comment: Also, your current `cycleST` performs *all the previous writes on a new array* on every iteration (quadratic complexity overall). That's because you don't actually modify an *array*, instead you build an ever-growing *array-modifying action*, which then you run with `runSTArray`. Is this the intended behaviour?

Comment: I guess I hadn't thought about it properly. Is there away around that problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68538/discussion-between-andras-kovacs-and-thecriticalimperitive).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to cleanly combine a stateful action having side effects, a delay, and an independent stopping condition.

The [iterative monad transformer](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-4.10.0.1/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Iter.html) from the `free` package can be useful in these cases.

This monad transformer lets you describe a (possibly nonending) computation as a series of discrete steps. And what's better, it let's you interleave "stepped" computations using `mplus`. The combined computation stops when any of the individual computations stops.

Some preliminary imports:

```
import Data.Bool
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Control.Monad.Trans.Iter (delay,untilJust,IterT,retract,cutoff)
import Control.Concurrent
```

Your `foobar` function could be understood as a "sum" of three things:

- A computation that does nothing but reading from the `MVar` at each step, and finishes when the `Mvar` is `True`.

  ```
  untilTrue :: (MonadIO m) => MVar Bool -> IterT m ()  
  untilTrue = untilJust . liftM guard . liftIO . readMVar
  ```
- An infinite computation that takes a delay at each step.

  ```
  delays :: (MonadIO m) => Int -> IterT m a
  delays = forever . delay . liftIO . threadDelay
  ```
- An infinite computation that prints an increasing series of numbers.

  ```
  foobar' :: (MonadIO m) => Int -> IterT m a 
  foobar' x = do
      let x' = x + 1
      liftIO (print x')
      delay (foobar' x')
  ```

With this in place, we can write `foobar` as:

```
foobar :: (MonadIO m) => MVar Bool -> m ()
foobar v =  retract (delays 1000000 `mplus` untilTrue v `mplus` foobar' 0)
```

The neat thing about this is that you can change or remove the "stopping condition" and the delay very easily.

Some clarifications:

- The `delay` function is not a delay in IO, it just tells the iterative monad transformer to "put the argument in a separate step".
- `retract` brings you back from the iterative monad transformer to the base monad. It's like saying "I don't care about the steps, just run the computation". You can combine `retract` with [`cutoff`](https://gist.github.com/danidiaz/e9382127d1c4025b9845) if you want to limit the maximum number of iterations.
- `untilJust`converts a value `m (Maybe a)` of the base monad into a `IterT m a` by retrying in each step until a `Just` is returned. Of course, this risks non-termination!

Comment: IterT has a quite a lot of functionality. I'm reading through the documentation right now and it will take some time to get my head around. Your answer was very detailed and is helping a lot! Would you have any extra recommended reading that might help?

Comment: @TheCriticalImperitive Here are some more examples: https://gist.github.com/ocharles/556b35e3d16565cab457 https://gist.github.com/danidiaz/e9382127d1c4025b9845 The iterative monad transformer is isomorphic to the special case of the free monad in which the functor is Identity, so tutorials on free monads could shed some light as well. And I think the transformer is also similar to a `Producer` from `pipes` that emits no useful information at each step: `IterT IO a` similar to `Producer () IO a`.

Comment: I think `foobar'` would be cleaner written as `foobar' = interleave_ [liftIO (print x) | x <- [0..]]`

Answer (score 3):

`MPredicate` is rather superfluous here; `m Bool` can be used instead. The [monad-loops](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-loops) package contains plenty of control structures with `m Bool` conditions. `whileM_` in particular is applicable here, although we need to include a `State` monad for the `Int` that we're threading around:

```
import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Monad.Loops
import Control.Applicative

foobar :: MVar Bool -> IO ()
foobar mvb = (`evalStateT` (0 :: Int)) $ 
  whileM_ (not <$> lift (readMVar mvb)) $ do
    modify (+1) 
    lift . print =<< get    
    lift $ threadDelay 1000000
```

Alternatively, we can use a monadic version of `unless`. For some reason `monad-loops` doesn't export such a function, so let's write it:

```
unlessM :: Monad m => m Bool -> m () -> m ()
unlessM mb action = do
  b <- mb
  unless b action
```

It's somewhat more convenient and more modular in a monadic setting, since we can always go from a pure `Bool` to `m Bool`, but not vice versa.

```
foobar :: MVar Bool -> IO ()
foobar mvb = go 0
    where
        go :: Int -> IO ()
        go x = unlessM (readMVar mvb) $ do 
            let x' = x + 1
            print x'
            threadDelay 1000000
            go x'
```

You mentioned `fix`; sometimes people indeed use it for ad-hoc monadic loops, for example:

```
printUntil0 :: IO ()
printUntil0 = 
  putStrLn "hello"

  fix $ \loop -> do
    n <- fmap read getLine :: IO Int
    print n
    when (n /= 0) loop

  putStrLn "bye"
```

With some juggling it's possible to use `fix` with multi-argument functions. In the case of `foobar`:

```
foobar :: MVar Bool -> IO ()
foobar mvb = ($(0 :: Int)) $ fix $ \loop x -> do
    unlessM (readMVar mvb) $ do
      let x' = x + 1
      print x'
      threadDelay 1000000
      loop x'
```

Comment: `monad-loops` package looks really interesting. Also the laziness component didn't even cross my mind, I guess I still get stuck in imperative mindset from time to time. IterT from the other answer is more where I was going because of the composability.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's your `MPredicate` is doing.
First, instead of newtyping a tuple, it's probably better to use a normal algebric data type

`data MPredicate a m = MPredicate a (a -> m Bool)`

Second, the way you use it, `MPredicate` is equivalent to `m Bool`.
Haskell is lazzy, therefore there is no need to pass, a function and it's argument (even though
it's usefull with strict languages). Just pass the result, and the function will be called when needed.

I mean, instead of passing `(x, f)` around, just pass `f x` 
Of course, if you are not trying to delay the evaluation and really need at some point, the argument or the function as well as the result, a tuple is fine.

Anyway, in the case your `MPredicate` is only there to delay the function evaluation, `MPredicat` reduces to `m Bool` and `doUnless` to `unless`.

Your first example is strictly equivalent :

```
main = do
   b <- newMVar False
   unless (readMVar b) (print "foo")
```

Now, if you want to loop a monad until a condition is reach (or equivalent) you should have a look at the [monad-loop](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-loops-0.3.0.2) package. What you are looking it at is probably `untilM_` or equivalent.